# Would appreciate a routing configuration advice

Tags: networking, routing, wifi, astaro

I have a problem with a host visibility which I think is caused by incomplete network configuration. There is an ADSL-router which has a DMZ subnet 192.168.0/24. In this network there is a wireless hotspot which provides internet access for visitors in its own subnet 172.24.0/24 and a firewall that serves the office LAN in its own subnet 10.35.0/24.
In the LAN, there is a server which is avaialable from internet but it is not available through our wireless network.

Obviously, our firewall needs some additional routing configuration, however I am not really familiar with Astaro hardware, so I would appreciate an advice regarding how to make the server available through our wireless network. Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Thanks!

Comment: What model routers and firewalls? How are they connected?

Comment: Firewall is Astaro (now Sophos) ASG120. It is the central point of the network and everything is connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

OK Its an odd setup you have but you will need a static route on your access point pointing to the firewall DMZ IP for the LAN network and a static route on the firewall pointing to the DMZ IP of the access point for the 172.24.0/24. This should route the traffic there and back again.

You will also need rules on the firewall allowing traffic from the wifi network to the server. Also make sure the nat is correct on the firewall and AP. you will need to ensure that there is no nat performed on the traffic going to and from the wifi/lan network.